# How to change maximum memory allowed for function in OpenWhisk

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openwhisk

I have an OpenWhisk deployment on a Kubernetees cluster that was done using [1]. I know I can change the memory limit for a function by adding `--memory x` when creating the function. However, if I try to set a value large than 512MB I get the following error.

```
requirement failed: memory 812 MB exceeds allowed threshold of 536870912 B (code 10543)
```

I assume this is a configuration set during the setup or within the code. Is there a way to increase this limit to a custom value? if so what is the configuration I need to perform in order to do this?

[1] https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-deploy-kube

Comment: Not the purpose of this question, but `--memory x` was all I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory limits are configurable for your deployment as of this patch https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/pull/3148. You can set the max memory in your deployment to suite your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the environment variable `CONFIG_whisk_memory_max=1073741824` on the invoker with a higher value for example 1GB
One way to edit the invoker deployment file
https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/kubernetes/invoker/invoker-dcf.yml#L74

```
- name: "CONFIG_whisk_memory_max"
  value: "1073741824"
```

Comment: I can't find the file linked.

Answer (score 0):

With ansible-playbook, you can specify an option with `-e limit_action_memory_max=1073741824` when you deploy openwhisk. The whole command might be like

```sh
ansible-playbook openwhisk.yml -e limit_action_memory_max=1073741824 # with other options like '-e invoker_user_memory=25600m'
```